# Powershell Script to get shared mailboxes from OU with last accessed time and size

Tags: powershell, exchange

I am currently tryng to produce a list of all shared mailboxes on the system including last accessed time and size of each mailbox. A lot of the "shared mailboxes" have been created as a normal mailbox with access granted to many users. Currently this is my script but I'm not even getting the test.csv created.

> Get-Mailbox -Org "domain/x/x/Shared Mailboxes" | Get-MailboxStatistics | sort lastlogontime -descending| select Displayname,last* | Export-Csv C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the cmldets correctly? 
Please look at the help files and the examples.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailboxstatistics?view=exchange-ps

```
# get function / cmdlet details
Get-Command -Name Get-Mailbox -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Get-Mailbox).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Mailbox -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Mailbox -Online
Get-help -Name Get-Mailbox -Examples

Get-Command -Name Get-MailboxStatistics -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Get-MailboxStatistics).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-MailboxStatistics -Full
Get-help -Name Get-MailboxStatistics -Online
Get-help -Name Get-MailboxStatistics -Examples
```

If you are not getting anything , that simply means your script results are null. Never do a whole script need to end. Always, always, step thru one segment at a time to make sure you are getting the results you think you should be getting, Leave the write to file stuff until all shows on screen first. So, comment out or delete the Export-Csv thing for now, until you figure out why you are getting nothing.

```
# Step one
Get-Mailbox -Org "domain/x/x/Shared Mailboxes"
# Are results returned - of not, stop and figure out why.

# Step 2
Get-Mailbox -Org "domain/x/x/Shared Mailboxes" | Get-MailboxStatistics 
# Are results returned - of not, stop and figure out why.

# if the above either of the above fail, then all else does not matter.

# Get all mailboxes for the specified OU
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*').DistinguishedName[3])

# Get mailbox for the specified OU, for a specified user in that OU
(Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*').DistinguishedName[3])).Alias[3]

# Get mailbox for the specified OU, for a specified user statistics in that OU
(Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*').DistinguishedName[3])).Alias[3] | 
Get-MailboxStatistics

# Get all the statistics info, for all mailboxes, selecting only the fields of interest
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $((Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter '*').DistinguishedName[3]) | 
Get-MailboxStatistics | 
Sort-Object LastLogonTime -descending | 
Select-Object DisplayName,LastLogonTime
```